# Problem understanding impedance measurement device accuracy format

Tags: batteries, impedance, instrumentation, accuracy

I am reading the datasheet of an impedance measurement device. Its accuracy is listed as '*±0.4% rdg. ±8 dgt.*'. What does '*rdg.*' and '*dgt.*' mean? And how should I interpret the accuracy?
The device is HIOKI BT4560. And I'll attach an image and here's the [link](http://www.testequipmentdepot.com/hioki/pdf/bt4560_datasheet.pdf) to the document

[image]

Comment: https://overseas.sanwa-meter.co.jp/support/faq_detail.php?id=21

Comment: Note that the "big print" accuracy claims are almost always "optimistic" compared to the fine print. See page 7 for the latter, and don't forget the temperature coefficient errors which are in addition to all the others.

Comment: ** meaning that the errors double over a 10'C ambient range

Answer (score 3):

"rdg" means **reading** and "dgt" means **digit**. This specification means that there are two defined types of error.

First, there is an error of up to \$\pm 0.4\$% of the meter reading. Multiply the displayed value by 0.004 to find the actual value of this error. For the displayed value of \$1.1424 \mathrm{m}\Omega\$ the error is about \$\pm 4.57\mu\Omega\$.

Second, there is an error of \$\pm8\$ in the least significant digit of the display. For the example you provide, the place value of the least significant digit in the display is \$0.1\mu\Omega\$ so there is an additional error contribution of \$\pm 0.8\mu\Omega\$.

So you have a total error specification of \$\pm 5.37\mu\Omega\$ for this measurement. The errors in digital meters are typically specified in this way, as a percentage of the reading and as a fixed multiple of the least significant digit.

Answer (score 1):

The Reading error is a GAIN error ( both linear & nonlinear) or 1/250 max

The Digit error is due to offset and noise where Digit error = 8/30k if full scale or 8/3175 in this X example = 0.3175 +/-0.0008

Modern Hybrid vehicle busbars have an impedance of < < 1uΩ to be efficient with Cap ESR's in the same range Shunted with batteries to improve charge efficiency and reduce pulse current losses I^2*ESR.

BTW this is a very good instrument for < $6k